# Not able to send files with the new file sharing system of uTorrent

Tags: file-sharing, utorrent

I'm trying to send my friend a .torrent with a lot of files from my PC. I made the torrent, but when I send her the link, this pops up:

*Source computer not turned on! This will not work unless the torrent is already seeded by several others. Ask your friend to turn on their computer and run µTorrent*

And she can't download it. What should I check ? I've used this before and it worked. Now at every torrent I make it says the same thing. Could it be a blocked port ? Please help!

PS: I'm not looking for alternatives. I have a lot of files to send. For example this torrent I'm trying to send now is about 200 GB.

Comment: Obvious question - but is the source computer turned on? Is the URL correct?

Comment: Yes, it's my PC. It's always turned on. And the URL should be correct, it's the one the uTorrent automatically makes it in a tinyurl.

Comment: Maybe i'm misunderstanding... But if it's a torrent of *your* files then you don't want *others* seeding just for your friend to receive?! Security!

Comment: Ok, please.. if you don't know how the new uTorrent works I don't think you'll be able to help me. It uses a public tracker for announce, but only the person with the link to it can download it. It's private.

Answer (score 2):

Your torrent file is in `C:\Users\Vio(username)\AppData\Roaming\uTorrent`. After you seed your private torrent, you will find the name of the torrent there.

Answer (score 0):

Your router or a firewall may be interfering.  Make sure the port used by uTorrent on your system is reachable from outside your network.

Comment: I have the uTorrent port forwarded.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are trying to use the built in tracker feature.  While I haven't used this particular feature myself, this tutorial seems to have some good info on it.  Notably, it seems that having your IP address change at any time will completely break it.

http://bootstrike.com/Articles/CreateTorrent/

Comment: I've tried using the built-in tracker as well. That doesn't work either. The one I'm trying to use is the new one introduced in the v3 of uTorrent. Wich is much more faster.

Comment: Hmm, which 3rd party tracker are you using? http://openbittorrent.com/ ?

Comment: udp://tracker.openbittorrent.com:80/announce and 
udp://tracker.publicbt.com:80/announce

Comment: I'll check this out some more when I get home tonight.  I'm still on a v2 of uTorrent, so I'll see if I can find anything useful out.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have nothing new to report. Testing on my network at home didn't give me any issue, but I didn't have a chance to test with an external user.